# Rate of convergence with matlab

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

I am supposed to determine the order of convergence of Heun's method just by evaluating $ y'(t)=\lambda y(t)$ for several $\lambda$, several step sizes and several number of grid points.

I already read that it is 2, but I do not know what I need to plot or which expression I need to evaluate in order to see this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you want to run your algorithm to time $T$. Assume with time step $h$ it takes $N$ steps, and thus with time step $h/2$ it will take $2N$ steps. This was hinted at above, but assuming at the outset (with $h$ the space step and $p$ the order of the method) that 
$$
e_{n, h} = Ah^p \Rightarrow \quad e_{2n, h/2} = A \left( \frac{h}{2} \right)^p
$$
and dividing gives 
$$
\frac{e_n,h}{e_{2n, h/2}} = 2^p.
$$
Thus, taking the log base two of this value gives that 
$$
p = \log_2 \left( \frac{e_n,h}{e_{2n, h/2}} \right)
$$
Taking a sequence of different steps and plotting the ratio will gives a clearer idea of this value of $p$, since for various reasons it will not be exact for every (h, N) pair.

Answer (score 1):

Obtain the exact solution $z(t)$.

The **local error** of an approximation scheme is the error after one step. Compute the error $e(h)$ of a single step at various step sizes from a particular point. A method is said to be $n$th order if $e(h)= A h^n +o(h^n)$ for some constant $A$.

How could you work out what $n$ should be given $e(h)\approx A h^n$? **Hint** : Taking logarithms might help.

Comment: but if n is constant then ln(A)*n is a constant, such that $ln(e(h))=ln(A)n ln(h)$. so all I will get is $ln(A)n$ and not n directly?

Comment: $\log (Ah^n)= \log A + \log h^n = \log A + n \log h$. What happens if you graph $\log e(h)$ against $\log h$?